# Why this Javascript quicksort method only return one character in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, quicksort

```
var arr = [4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 4, 2,];

function quickSort(arra) {
    if (arra.length <= 1) {
        return arra;
    }
    else {
        var len    = arra.length;
        var left   = [];
        var right  = [];
        var temp   = arra.pop();
        var newarr = [];

        for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            if (arra[i] < temp) {
                left.push(arra[i]);
            }
            else { right.push[i]; }
        }
    }
    return newarr.concat(quickSort(left), temp, quickSort(right));
}

console.log(quickSort(arr))
```

The result is:

[image: Console image showing output]

I wonder why this method only return me one character in the array?

Comment: Use `let` and `const`. Repleace `newarr` to `[]`. Change `right.push[i]` to `right.push(arra[i])`.

Comment: Why don't you just use [`arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

Answer (score 0):

`pop()` method removes last element from array (so length decreases by 1) and first element has index 0 so you need to replace your for loop with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {
```

Also you need to change `right.push[i]` as mentioned in comments.